# Bug using quick select algo for Leetcode 973

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm using quick select algo to solve this problem and I encountered `Max call stack exceeded` error for the following algo, but couldn't figure out where the bug is:

https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/description/

> We have a list of points on the plane.  Find the K closest points to the origin (0, 0).
>
> (Here, the distance between two points on a plane is the Euclidean distance.)
>
> You may return the answer in any order.  The answer is guaranteed to be unique (except for the order that it is in.)

Code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} points
 * @param {number} K
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
var kClosest = function(points, K) {
    quickSelect(points, K, 0, points.length - 1)
    return points.slice(0, K)
};

function quickSelect(points, K, low, high) {
  if (low >= high) return;
  const partitionIndex = partition(points, low, high);
  if (partitionIndex === K - 1) 
    return;
  if (partitionIndex < K - 1) {
    quickSelect(points, K, partitionIndex + 1, high);
  } else {
    quickSelect(points, K, low, partitionIndex - 1);
  }
}

function partition(points, low, high) {
  const pivot = points[(low+high)>>2]
  //console.log('pivot:', pivot, (low+high)>>2);
  
  while(low <= high){
    while(getDist(points[low]) < getDist(pivot)){
      low++;
    }
    while(getDist(points[high]) >getDist(pivot)){
      high--;
    }
    
    if(low <= high){
      swap(points, low, high);
      low++;
      high--;
    }
  }
  
  return low;
}

function getDist(point) {
  return point[0] * point[0] + point[1] * point[1];
}

function swap(arr, i, j) {
  [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just `sort` them?

Comment: Sorting doesn't produce optimal solution. Quick select gives you `O(n)` run time vs. sorting `O(n log n)`

Comment: @guest Does it? I mean, you may be correct for the average case it is, but worst case time complexity of QuickSelect algorithm is `O(N^2)`, which is inferior to a sorting algorithm with `O(NlogN)` worst case time complexity.

Comment: `pivot = points[(low+high)>>2]` is wrong.  You want `pivot = points[(low+high)>>1]`

Comment: You're right! it fixed it. @MattTimmermans there are some edge cases I need to fix, but for the most part, it works now. bit shifting 1 digit is like /2 that was my issue, not bit shifting by 2

Comment: @ilim You're right that quick sort produces `O(n^2)` for worst case, however quick select does not. The difference between the two is that quick select does not "sort" individual elements inside the array, it only cares about whether the pivot produces a partition that allows you to select top k elements. The left and right partitions around the pivot index don't have to be sorted. This is why quick select will always stay at `O(n)` because you all you're doing is stepping through the array and do the swap.

Comment: Quickselect will not _always_ have linear time complexity. Whether all the elements are sorted or not is irrelevant. In the worst case, you will always pick the worst possible pivot. Your partitioning will reduce the array size only by 1 at each recursive step, leading to quadratic time complexity. You may refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Time_complexity) as another resource.

Comment: @ilim of course it's relevant whether the left or right half is sorted. If you have a solution that leaves left and right partitions unsorted, it's a no brainer that the runtime is less than another solution that sorts both left and right half. Essentially it's always less than a sorted `O(n log n)`

That Wikipedia reference DOES say for any random pivot, it is deterministically linear. That means that it converges almost surely to linear. If you are looking at some edge cases that is outside that is probably not within discussion for a Leetcode question.